# Have different tabs/windows remembering their mode

Tags: gvim, insert-mode, vim-windows, normal-mode

I have done a bit of research about this but found only very old answers, [like this one](http://vim_use.narkive.com/2WmlB8vD/buffer-local-mode), and all on the negative side.

My problem is the following --- suppose you are working on a document/program, say for example a LaTeX file. You have some error and you open another window/tab with the log file, which is opened in read-only mode (the same for the quickfix window).

Then you switch to insert mode in your main file, and *all* the windows/tabs/buffers enters insert mode. So I can't switch rapidly to the "log" windows/tab to scroll/move/hitting "q" to close it, because it's in input mode...

[image: example, log file in input mode]

So the question is — is it possible to remember the mode at a window/tab level?

I understand that it could have been confusing in the original `vi`, but with things like `airline` and colors it's quite handy to know the mode in which you are...

Comment: If you get used to staying in normal mode, you won't have such problems ... and the Vim "way" *is* normal mode.

Comment: @VanLaser yep, probably you're right. Will try to see if I can switch to normal mode every time I switch tab/window...

Comment: If you switch windows using Vim's maps that start with `Ctrl-w`, you have to be in normal mode anyway ...

Comment: How do you switch windows in the first place? With the mouse? I don't really understand how you get this problem in the first place...

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg yes, I admit with shame --- with the mouse...

Comment: @Rmano I haven't fully tested the code, so there may be cases where it doesn't work as expected but you could temporarily try adding the following in your vimrc: http://vpaste.net/0PFdV

Comment: @saginaw seems to work --- why don't you put it as an answer?

Comment: @Rmano Sorry, I was not sure it was exactly what you wanted and if it worked all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for Vim to remember if you are in insert mode or not for each window opened, you could add the following autocmds inside your vimrc:

```
augroup RememberMode
    autocmd!
    autocmd WinLeave * let w:mode_state = mode()
    autocmd WinEnter *
                \ if exists('w:mode_state') && w:mode_state ==# 'i' |
                \     startinsert |
                \ elseif exists('w:mode_state') && mode() ==# 'i' |
                \     stopinsert |
                \ endif
augroup END
```

The first one `autocmd WinLeave * let w:mode_state = mode()` stores the mode in which you are when you leave a window (`WinLeave` event) inside the window-local variable `w:mode_state` (you can change the name of the variable if you don't like it, but keep the window-local scope `w:`).

The second one tests, when you enter a window (`WinEnter` event), whether the window-local variable `w:mode_state` exists (because if it's a window you just created, it will not exist and the following test would probably raise an error), and if its value is `'i'`.
If it is, it means that the last time you left this window you were in insert mode, so Vim puts you back in insert mode with the Ex command `:startinsert`.

Otherwise, the autocmd tests whether `w:mode_state` exists and you're in insert mode. In this case, it means that you were already in this window in the past (otherwise the variable wouldn't exist), but you were not in insert mode (because this case has already been covered), you were in another mode. So Vim makes you quit insert mode with the Ex command `:stopinsert`.

---

For more information, see:

```
:help :augroup
:help :autocmd
:help WinLeave
:help WinEnter
:help w:
:help mode()
:help exists()
:help :startinsert
:help :stopinsert
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to be bold and claim that your problem will be solved if you learn to use Vim/vi without using the mouse. Learn to stay in normal mode on a default basis, from which changing the window can be done with `<c-w><c-w>`. You will be happier in the long term, even though this may take some effort and time in the short term.

*Note: I know this is not an answer to your actual question, and I'll accept being downvoted for that reason.*

Comment: No reason to downvote. It's a completely reasonable answer. I'll try....